# using bash script, get the list of dates from filenames in folder, list dates, list suffixes

Tags: linux, sorting, sed, filenames

I have several files of the type:

```
id2018.12.15.log
id2018.12.16.log
id2018.12.17_a.log
id2018.12.17_b.log
...
```

I would need to sort the distinct dates from these filenames, and also sort the suffixes.

I know that i need to use a combination  of cut, sed, sort commands. I also know that it would be best to store the output in a file but it's not necessarily key. any ideas please?

thanks.

Comment: You're very unlikely to get many responses without giving us examples of what you have tried and what has gone wrong, or atleast high level pseudo-code of logically how think this would happen.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yes, thank you. Ideally I would like to get the distinct list of dates from the files. then get the distinct list of suffixes from the files. I was thinking to use cut and sed to sort the two parts (dates and suffixes)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your files names are guaranteed to NOT contains space/newline:

```
$ ls -1
2018.12.18_z
id2018.12.15.log
id2018.12.16.log
id2018.12.17_a.log
id2018.12.17_b.log


$ printf '%s\n' * | grep -oP '\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}' | sort -u
2018.12.15
2018.12.16
2018.12.17
2018.12.18

$ printf '%s\n' * | grep -oP '\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}_\K\w+' | sort -u
a
b
z
```

Comment: thanks Gilles, I am trying to put your suggestion in my script, but the outcome is not the same as yours. I don't see the output actually.

Comment: Thanks to update your original post with expected output. Is there any error ? What is the output from my command ?

Comment: i see no difference in the output whether i do : ' ls -1 ' or the 'printf ...' command. i get the list of the files with their full name and not just the dates.

Comment: What is the output of `grep -oP ` alone ? `ls` is not a tool to be parsed : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: ah, my bad, i had omitted one pipe. it now shows the correct output as yours. But i would need two different commands, one to show only the distinct dates, and one for the suffixes only.

Comment: Thank you very much Gilles. I appreciate it.